# search excel file for matching text word, get row contents

Tags: python, excel, pandas, python-3.7

I am trying this logic; but it is outputting the below error, under it:

```
 data1 = pd.read_excel(config.Excel1)

 mask = np.column_stack([data1[col].str.contains("22801") for col in data1])
 data1.loc[mask.any(axis=1)]
```

error:

```
raise AttributeError("Can only use .str accessor with string " "values!")
```

I tried hard keying the zip as you can see "`22801`" which still didn't work, but want to use my `Zip` variable. But returned the accessor error.

Here is an example of what should be a match:

```
  |       'Member Address Line 3'         |
  Blah Blah Road, Hungary Spring, VA 22801
```

Comment: `np.column_stack([data1[col].astype(str).str.contains("22801") for col in data1])` ? I think the `data1[col]` has float/int not str

Comment: Just tried '.int' and got similar error. I've updated the OP for more context.